# per-user resolv.conf

Tags: dns

My linux server has differnt users [u01 - u04], can I have each user use a specific resolv.conf?

for example:

```
u01:  nameserver=10.14.15.123
u02:  nameserver=10.14.15.124
u03:  nameserver=10.14.16.125
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no, see [resolv.conf(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf). However if you really want this feature, you can reimplement the functions in [resolver(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/resolver) in a shared library, and use ld-magic to override the originals, at least in dynamically linked applications.